# Change of Basis of Polynoms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$
and $B'=\{1/2(x-1)(x-2),-x(x-2),1/2x(x-1)\}$.

Find the transition matrix from B to B' and the transition matrix from B' to B.

I was able to find the transition matrix from B' to B but I can't find the solution for the transition matrix from B to B'.

Comment: It’s the inverse of the matrix that you’ve computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have the matrix T s.t.:

$$TB' = B$$

then the transition matrix from B to B' will be given by:

$$B' = T^{-1}B$$

Essentially, just find the inverse of your $3$ x $3$ matrix T.